# "display:inline-block" displays differently than "display:inline flow-root"

Tags: css

I have the following division container:

```
<span> Lorem. </span>
<div style="display: inline-block; background-color: yellow;">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, officia? </p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta, ab. </p>
</div>
<span> Lorem. </span>
```

As expected, the division container acts like an inline-level element.

When I alter the value of the display property to "inline flow-root", the division container no longer acts like an inline-level element and instead acts like a block-level element:

```
<span> Lorem. </span>
<div style="display: inline flow-root; background-color: yellow;">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, officia? </p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta, ab. </p>
</div>
<span> Lorem. </span>
```

According to the [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#legacy), the "inline-block" value should be equivalent to "inline flow-root".

Why does the two values produce different display results?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `display: inline flow-root` is getting disabled with warning as `invalid property value` and it is providing its default property value which is `block`

Comment: [Can I start to use the two-value syntax?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display/two-value_syntax_of_display#can_i_start_to_use_the_two-value_syntax) Are you running this in Firefox, the only browser that has implemented it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967550/why-is-display-flow-root-invalid-in-mobile),

```
display: flow-root; Needs Chrome Canary or Firefox Nightlies.

sets it to display: table; or display: block;

May be you can use overflow: visiible to contain float-ed elements.
```